# How to detect a Gimbal Proximity Beacon, Series 10 in android?

Tags: android

How to detect a Gimbal Proximity Beacon, Series 10 in android.

```
private void checkContextConnectorStatus() {
    if (contextCoreConnector.isPermissionEnabled()) {
        // Gimbal is already enabled
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Gimbal is already enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {

        contextCoreConnector.enable(this, new Callback<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Void responseObject) {
                Log.d("", "Gimbal enabled"+responseObject);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(int statusCode, String errorMessage) {
                Log.d("", "Failed to initialize gimbal " + errorMessage);
            }
        });
    }
```

I use this code but it is always show same output.
First time that shows "Gimbal enabled" than after that "Gimbal is already enabled" shows.
So, How to detect Gimbal.